# how to display legend iterating over list of values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to plot a dummy graph with several lines and a legend in which each of the values in the list "label" will be displayed once for each of the corresponding lines.

In the following MWE, each line of the legend has all the values of the list "label" and I want to iterate over the list.

```
y = np.random.rand(1,300).reshape(50,6)
x = np.repeat(np.array([range(1,7)]), 50, axis=0)
label = [70, 50, 30, 10, 30, 50]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, marker='+', label=label)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

If I try to make a loop over the list, I get single values for the legend, but each value repeated several times and I don't want to repeat values:

```
y = np.random.rand(1,300).reshape(50,6)
x = np.repeat(np.array([range(1,7)]), 50, axis=0)
label = [70, 50, 30, 10, 30, 50]

plt.figure()
for i in label:
    plt.plot(x, y, marker='+', label='{i}'.format(i=i))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell explicitely how the legend should look like and how the shown markers (and their color) should relate to the 36 lines? Do you actually want to have 36 lines in the plot (since it seems they are the same)? I would suggest you show the graph with the lines you want and then describe what you want to show in the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
p = plt.plot(x, y, marker='+')
plt.legend(p, label)
```